# Auth::attempt not working on laravel passport api

Tags: laravel, eloquent

This is My Login Attempt :

```
public function loginUser(Request $request){
   $rules = [
       'email' => 'required',
       'password' => 'required'
   ];
   $this->validate($request, $rules);
   //attempting login
   if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])){
    return 'hello';
   }
   return 'null';

}
```

This is my auth config :

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

'api' => [
    'driver' => 'passport',
    'provider' => 'users',
    //'hash' => false,
],
],

'providers' => [
'users' => [
    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'model' => App\Models\User::class,
],

// 'users' => [
//     'driver' => 'database',
//     'table' => 'users',
// ],
],
```

This is My data structure :

```
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->integer('verified')->unsigned();
        $table->string('verification_token')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

When i am calling this loginUser function From my api route it's giving me null even though the credentials i am passing is valid;
And I am using bcrypt password;

Comment: what is your default guard ?

Comment: it's session and i changed it to api know and i have a new exception saying Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::attempt does not exist .

Comment: `Auth::guard('web')->attempt()` this is possible but  `Auth::guard('api')->attempt()` cannot possible